# Symfony 2 SecurityContext class deprecated

Tags: security, symfony

I get the following error when I try to reach app/example on symfony demo

> Error: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is
>   deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage
>   or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker
>   instead.

The server is returning the right answer with a 200 status code though.

I've found nothing on Google about it. Has anybody encounter this error before and/or know how to fix it ?

Comment: Disable the warning with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7

Comment: I have this same issue, caused by FOSUserBundle which is still using the deprecated call and doesn't seem to be updated even in the 2.0dev version.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Explanation**

Starting with Symfony 2.6 the  `SecurityContext` got split into the `TokenStorage` and the `AuthorizationChecker` (see: [Symfony Blog - "New in Symfony 2.6: Security component improvements"](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements)).

The main reason for this was to prevent circular reference which occurred quite often when injecting the `SecurityContext` into your own services.

**Solution**

The change itself is 100% backwards compatible (as stated in the linked blog post), you just need to rewrite how you accessed the `SecurityContext`.

```
// Symfony 2.5
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
// Symfony 2.6
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

// Symfony 2.5
if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) { ... }
// Symfony 2.6
if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) { ... }
```

You can simply try to find the culprit by doing a text-search for `security.context` or `SecurityContext` in your source code (including the vendor directory).

But as you stated that you're using vanilla Symfony 2.6 it seems that it simply uses some soon to be deprecated methods. So you might simply use this...

**Workaround**

As Symfony does it's deprecation by triggering `E_USER_DEPRECATED` errors, you can simply disable them when booting your Symfony `AppKernel`:

```
// app/AppKernel.php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function __construct($environment, $debug) {
        // Keep error reporting like it was and disable only deprecation warnings.
        error_reporting(error_reporting() & (-1 ^ E_DEPRECATED));
        // ...
    }
}
```

I personally like the deprecation warnings, because Symfony's changelogs tend to give very detailed information on how you need to change your code to support future versions of Symfony and the deprecation warnings normally are triggered months before the methods are actually deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear anwser. I like deprecated warnings too, the problem was they were spoiling my newRelic monitoring.

Comment: Flu could you please advise how one may use annotation security system with new classes?

Comment: @Abdel5 I think it would be better to put this into a question on your own as this question here is solely about getting rid of the error the OP was having trouble with.

Comment: Thank u @flu. You saved my several hours!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a proper error, just a warning.

A deprecated class is a class that is planned to be removed in future releases (of Symfony, in this case).

It suggest you to stop using it, and points you to the newer (and substitutes) class, `TokenStorage` and `AuthorizationChecker`, that will take completly over to do the same tasks.

Comment: The thing is, I've just forked and deployed the [symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard) so I have no idea where the deprecated class is used. In addition, even though it's only a warning, it completely spoils my new relic monitoring : that's why I want to get rid of it.

Comment: So, that's completly normal, there's some deprecated code inside Symfony. You could try Symfony 2.7 or put an ignore under New Relic.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying Symfony 2.7" ? The symfony-standard repo is already based on Symfony 2.7, isn't it ?

Comment: But still, I've got these deprecated warnings. Is it possible to configure Symfony to avoid those ?

Comment: You could configure your php.ini to ignore them

Answer (score 0):

It gets so annoying to see that warning. At the same time you don't want to turn off the warnings. So I thought maybe it's useful to give an example of changing your code to get rid of it. Here's how I changed `HWIOAuthBundle`'s `OAuthUtils` class to do so.
First, I changed `/vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI/Bundle/OAuthBundle/Resources/config/oauth.html` from this:

```
<service id="hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" class="%hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="security.http_utils" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    <argument>%hwi_oauth.connect%</argument>
</service>
```

to this:

```
<service id="hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils" class="%hwi_oauth.security.oauth_utils.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="security.http_utils" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.authorization_checker" />
    <argument>%hwi_oauth.connect%</argument>
</service>
```

Now we have to change it in the `/vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/HWI/Bundle/OAuthBundle/Security/OAuthUtils` class from this:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
    ...

    /**
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * @param HttpUtils                $httpUtils
     * @param SecurityContextInterface $securityContext
     * @param boolean                  $connect
     */
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, $connect)
    {
        $this->httpUtils       = $httpUtils;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->connect         = $connect;
    }
```

to this:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
    ...

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationChecker
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @param HttpUtils                $httpUtils
     * @param AuthorizationChecker     $authorizationChecker
     * @param boolean                  $connect
     */
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, $connect)
    {
        $this->httpUtils            = $httpUtils;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->connect              = $connect;
    }
```

Then I made changes where the `securityContext` was used. Replaced it with `authorizationChecker`.

```
    public function getAuthorizationUrl(Request $request, $name, $redirectUrl = null, array $extraParameters = array())
    {
        $resourceOwner = $this->getResourceOwner($name);
        if (null === $redirectUrl) {
            if (!$this->connect || !$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
                $redirectUrl = $this->httpUtils->generateUri($request, $this->ownerMap->getResourceOwnerCheckPath($name));
            } else {
                $redirectUrl = $this->getServiceAuthUrl($request, $resourceOwner);
            }
        }

        return $resourceOwner->getAuthorizationUrl($redirectUrl, $extraParameters);
    }
```

The reason of replacing SecurityContext with AuthorizationChecker is because only isGranted method is used in this case. Maybe you could replace it with TokenStorage or use both AuthorizationChecker and TokenStorage if you needed for your case.