# Security annotations and The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated

Tags: symfony

According to Symfony begining with version 3.0 `The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext` will be removed. This was already discussed here: [Symfony 2 SecurityContext class deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606237/symfony-2-securitycontext-class-deprecated)

My symfony reports the following error:

> Error: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is
>   deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage
>   or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker
>   instead.

I am using `annotations` to manage my security roles in symfony e.g.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security; // Security annotation bundle

    /**
 * @Route("/account/list", name="Account_list")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
```

**How should I switch into non-depreciated class?**

Using either of the classes listed in error results in:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Security" in method
>   AppBundle\Controller\AccountController::listAction() was never
>   imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this
>   annotation? in
>   /var/www/gra.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/Controller/
>   (which is being imported from
>   "/var/www/gra.investmentopportunities.pl/app/config/routing.yml").

Comment: You should still use the `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security`  annotation. Are you sure that this deprecation warning is due to the annotation? There should be no warning just from using the `@Security` tag on it's own since this commit - https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/commit/675a6ea953c46721e57d692d17bb8d4a734b92f8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at [the code](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/v3.0.5/EventListener/SecurityListener.php) it looks like the `@security.context` was used up until `v3.0.4`. From then on `@security.token_storage` and `@security.authorization_checker` were also injected so that, if they were present, they would be used instead of the `@security.context`.

Taken from those facts I can only assume that are using a version of the `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` previous to `v3.0.5`.

If you have `sensio/framework-extra-bundle: ~3.0` in your `composer.json` then you can just run `composer.phar update sensio/framework-extra-bundle` and it should bring it up to date and get rid of the deprecation warnings.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have checked the composer and I am currently using v. 3.0.9 of sensio/framework-extra-bundle. The question is what command should I "use" at the script header for annotations to work? (see updated code above).