# How to ignore deprecated messages in log related to 3rd party bundles?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

After updating Symfony to 2.7 version it started to log `DEPRECATED` notices in the log. It is a good thing. And I want use the whole power of this feature.

But now it is very hard to find any deprecated notice related to my own bundle. Many of deprecations are from `vendor` folder. And I want to completely ignore `vendor` folder in this case. Then I will see messages related to my bundle only.

[image]

Comment: Check here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7

Comment: @SujataHalwai, it is not the same. I want to ignore only **one folder**. Not the whole code.

Comment: The 3 first errors are linked to the Distribution bundle, did you changed `"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",` to `"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",` in your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score -2):

Read 
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/upgrade/deprecation_warnings.html

Resume :

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to show only your deprecated Warning, you should try/catch the E_USER_DEPRECATED Warning and propagate it only if it's related to your bundle

Comment: *you should try/catch* How would you do that?