# Using a Factory to Create Services with symfony2.7

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

How to use factory to create services with symfony2.7 ?

```
#service.yml
#in symfony 2.6
my.repository.photo:
    class: My\AppBundle\Repository\PhotoRepository
    factory_method: getRepository
    factory_service: doctrine
    arguments: [My\AppBundle\Entity\Photo]

#I have some errors like this
Deprecated: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(getRepository) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead. in /my/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php on line 137
Deprecated: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryService(doctrine) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead. in my/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php on line 208
```

How to use "setFactory" method now in my case ?
Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think related documentation is clear. Try this configuration:

```
my.repository.photo:
    class: My\AppBundle\Repository\PhotoRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
    arguments: [My\AppBundle\Entity\Photo]
```

Deprecated errors are an preparation for upcomming Symfony 3.0. Some features (like factory_service|factory_method) will be removed. Here is a thread where you can find solutions [to disabling Symfony deprecated errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7) if you really don't need it.