# Remove "Remaining deprecation notices" in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm new on Symfony and PHPUnit.

I would like to run some tests, there are a lot of deprecation notices. But it does not matter because I'll stay on Symfony 2.8 for now. Do you know if it's possible to remove them?

[image]

I try to find out by myself, but it's not working, have you got some ideas for me folks ?

[How to remove the deprecation warnings in Symfony 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284480/how-to-remove-the-deprecation-warnings-in-symfony-2-7)

[Disable deprecated warning in Symfony 2(.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7)

---

**EDIT :**

Reference to the answer of @LBA

My screenshot is not really about the error of the AsseticBundle, but about the "Remaining deprecation notices (220)". I would like to know if there is a flag somewhere to display, or not, these warnings. I would like to just have the result of my test suit. Is that possible?

Comment: It's do matter because it's deprecated in 2.8.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Finally found the solution !

Just add

```
<php>
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak" />
</php>
```

to your `phpunit.xml` (or any other file that you use to configure phpunit)

Comment: For reference, see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-deprecation-helper-improvements#limiting-the-number-of-triggered-deprecations.

Comment: I had the same problem in Symfony 4.3 with Codeception and that solution does the job.

Comment: Or instead `weak` set value `disabled`.

Comment: Okay with @r-picheta. Setting value to `disabled` is the right solution when you need to completely remove the noise produced by deprecation notices.

Comment: ```<env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="/disabled=1/"/>```

Answer (score 25):

You can run in terminal

```
export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=weak
```

Before executing your script. It will disable deprecation notices

Comment: I don't know why but this is the only answer that works for me. When I change the value in the phpunit xml file it is never refreshed and taken in account by the test suite.

Comment: it might be because you're using something else than phpunit.xml as your configuration file for phpunit

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue of the AsseticBundle which isn't part of the official Symfony distribution anymore and not ready for 3.0 yet (having some deprecations in the current tagged version - which you can see in your error message).

So please follow and wait for this issue to be solved and update your AsseticBundle when it's ready (or go with the current master of it what I wouldn't recommend to do.

A lot of people trying to upgrade to Symfony 2.8/3.0 have this issue currently.

[Link to the Issue on Github](https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/401)

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I will follow. 
But I have edited my question : my concernes was more about the display of the depreciation notices. Do you know if we can decide to display or not theses logs ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of any option to not display it.