# Suppress deprecation warnings in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently upgrading from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 (we use only LTS releases).

There are a lot of deprecations which will need some time to be resolved. In the meantime these messages cost a lot of memory in dev mode (sometimes even leading to OOM errors) and spam the logs (~3 MB per request), so I would like to disable them completely.

So far I found only solutions for the log spam (configure Monolog), but not for the memory problem.

There is NO call to `Debug::enable()`. Adding the call explicitly with appropriate error reporting level has no effect.

Disabling error_reporting for E_USER_DEPRECATED has no effect.

There is a similar question which got no responses: [How to remove the deprecation warnings in Symfony 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284480/how-to-remove-the-deprecation-warnings-in-symfony-2-7) (the question is almost 3 years old, so I re-ask)

I investigated the Symfony source, but saw no possibility for changes either, as everything around error handling seems to be static.

Comment: You can disable the [deprecations helper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#disabling-the-deprecation-helper) by setting the environment variable `SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER` to `disabled`. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for PHPUnit tests (tested it nevertheless but with the expected outcome: nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to postpone the problem for a few days, then I noticed my mistake: The suggestion from this answer works if you don't mess up the Monolog config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779541/10249309