# Symfony2 dev.log since weeks I'm seeing this php.INFO lines

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

```
php.INFO: The "_method" requirement is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the setMethods() method instead. 
{"type":16384,"file":"/martin/home/www/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php","line":652,"level":28928}
```

php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

Symfony version 2.8.18

Does someone get this also ?  I'm trying to optimize the dev logging and get as few lines as possible.

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7

Comment: It is a backhanded message so it tells you to upgrade your symfony app.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this as a pre-caution before you decide to upgrade to Symfony 3. Since this is deprecated, you can (should) change your routing from something like:

```
$route = new Route();
$route->setPattern('/article/{id}');
$route->setRequirement('_method', 'POST|PUT');
$route->setRequirement('_scheme', 'https');
```

To:

```
$route = new Route();
$route->setPath('/article/{id}');
$route->setMethods(array('POST', 'PUT'));
$route->setSchemes('https');
```

Notice specially the change of `setRequirement('_method', ...` to `setMethods()` (what the dev log is suggesting basically).

You can find more info here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just wanted to mention that I'm not using Routes like this in the code any way, only annotations like * @Method("POST") in some controller actions.

Comment: So it's probably under bundle that is still using _method.  I suppose you could try searching the entire vendor directory for _method and then if you do find it see of that particular bundles has a 2.8 update.

Comment: @MartinFasani You may not be doing it like this yourself. But that is what is creating that log. As Cerad mentioned, it may be in another bundle.