# Turn off deprecated and strict errors when running tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to make working test suite of very old PHP project (Symfony 2.2.4, PHPUnit 4.8.36).

When i run tests, with command line `./phpunit -c app my/tests/path` i got symfony errors like:

```
bindRequest() is deprecated since version 2.1 and will be removed in 2.3. Use FormInterface::bind() instead.
```

I would like run tests without deprecated or strict errors for now. How to do that ?

Note: I don't have phpunit configuration file (and don't know how create it).
Note2: my php.ini already have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` in `/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`

Comment: add to your script "error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED) ); "

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I have this config in my php.ini. You say to add it in the top of file of .php script containg test ? I have a lot of php script with tests. I have to add it in all files ? There is no place to set it once ?

Comment: Looking at the message it looks more like it comes from the framework, not from PHP itself.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz If you think it comes from Symfony, do you know where to configure this ? Note: When run development server, deprecated and stricts don't produce fatal error.

Comment: Have you tried any of these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7

Comment: @Cerad yes i tried all of these, no change.

Comment: Even the AppKernel::init() method?  Seems strange.

Comment: @Cerad Yes Even Even the AppKernel::init() method ... I will investigate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution for me: Install this component:

```
composer require symfony/debug
```

And add this in `AppKernel#init`:

```
if ($this->debug ) {
    Debug::enable(E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED, false);
    // ...
```