# How to disable or fix deprecation warning within Symfony framework?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a command line tool using Symfony but whenever there's an error, it throws this kind of warning:

```
[php] User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent" class is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the ConsoleErrorEvent instead.
[
  "exception" => ErrorException {
    #message: "User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent" class is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the ConsoleErrorEvent instead."
    #code: 0
    #file: "./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Event/ConsoleExceptionEvent.php"
    #line: 14
    #severity: E_USER_DEPRECATED
    trace: {
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Event/ConsoleExceptionEvent.php:14 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php:146 { …}
      Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass() {}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:974 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:86 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:248 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:74 { …}
      ./vendor/xxxx/job-queue-bundle/JMS/JobQueueBundle/Console/Application.php:45 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:148 { …}
      ./bin/console:28 {
        › $application = new Application($kernel);
        › $application->run($input);
        ›
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So it seems the framework is throwing deprecation warning about its own classes. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Symfony version?  Just a guess but I suspect you need to move to 3.4.

Comment: It's v3.4, and upgrading Symfony is not an option.

Comment: Have you checked to see exactly where the exception is being thrown?  Maybe the third party JobQueueBundle needs an update.  I am assuming it is not your code tossing the exception.

Comment: Actually Doctrine is also showing these deprecation warnings. At this point, I would prefer to just turn off the warnings as upgrading everything is not really possible.

Comment: I have not tried this in 3.4 so can't really help.  There are several 2.x related questions out there that I would expect to work.  Similar to the now deleted answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7