# Possible to disable specific deprecation warnings in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. While testing the 3.4 project in `dev` mode the Symfony toolbar is a great help.

However the Symfony / the toolbar always logs/shows all warnings and notices, no matter if they are relevant to me or not.

For example I know that third party bundle XY is not ready for `Symfony 4` and thus includes some deprecated methods. I cannot change this and for the moment it does not matter.

However, I still would like to know if my own code uses deprecated methods to fix this now, since I am refactoring the code anyway.

I found different threads about this question, but the only solution was to disable warnings in general ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850809/disable-deprecated-warning-in-symfony-2-7)).

This would work to see no deprecation warnings at all, but as described I would like to remove / silence **specific** warnings only.

**Is it somehow possible to silence warnings form BundleA or ClassB while still seeing warnings from CodeC?**

I know that PHP it self cannot do this, but maybe there is some way to configure the dev toolbar to do this?

Comment: You could probably just set up a deprecations log file with monolog and filter that with grep if there's no straight forward way to filter this in the toolbar.

Comment: you will need a custom monolog handler where you will write your logic to suppress messages based on keywords/messages

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because deprecation warnings in Symfony are called as `trigger_error('Deprecation message', E_USER_DEPRECATED)`.

For example, see this [Twig DebugCommand](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Command/DebugCommand.php#L417).

Answer (score -2):

A temporary solution, update the description of the methods should be ok.

```
/**
 * Function
 * @deprecated it is deprecated.  <- remove
 */
function a() {
  return 'hi';
}
```

Comment: editing third party code is not a viable solution as the edits would be lost every time composer is run

Comment: On the other hand, I did run into one very annoying bundle that no longer appeared to be maintained.  I forked it, removed the deprecated annotations and went on my way until I could replace the functionality completely.  By this time at least, you would expect most maintained projects to support 3.4.